# Append list of lists from xml files

Tags: python, xml, list, indexing, glob

I have different XML files with some tags. When I want to append keywords from XML files  I am not able to append them with the same structure. Keywords are lists, so I would need a list of lists to append them.  When I tried the dictionary approach I was only indexing one tag per id, but not the whole list.

I was trying to do this with tuples and a zip but achieving the same result, one tag per id.

This is the basic code used for retreiving keywords.

```
keywords = [[] for i in range (4)]
for infil in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.xml') ):
   tree = et.parse(infil)
   root = tree.getroot()
   for keyword in root.find(".//keywords"):
           if keyword.text is not None:
                keywords.append(keyword.text)
```

I Will like to have an output like this, but I was only having a single list, not a list of lists.

```
 {'symbol': ['CEDAW/SP/1998/1',
 'CEDAW/SP/1998/2',
 'CEDAW/SP/1998/3',
 'CEDAW/SP/1998/4'],
 'jobno': ['N9801528', 'N9802769', 'N9801085', 'N9812464'],
 'dat': ['19980121', '19980206', '19980111', '19980501'],
 'language': ['English', 'English', 'English', 'English'],
 'keywords': [(['AGENDA'],
  ["WOMEN'S STATUS",
  'TREATIES',
  'SIGNATURES, ACCESSIONS, RATIFICATIONS',
  'RESERVATIONS AND DECLARATIONS',
  'GENDER DISCRIMINATION'],
   ['ELECTION OF MEMBERS', 'BIOGRAPHY'],
   ["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS'])]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're only specifying the top level list to append to. So when you do `[[], [], [], []].append(1)`, you will get `[[], [], [], [], 1]`.

You need to specify the inner list, like this `list[i].append(keyword.text)`, so you will need to obtain the index in some way.

```py
# make it scalable so it will work even if you add more XML files
paths = glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.xml') )
keywords = [[] for i in range(len(paths))

for i in range(len(paths)):
    tree = et.parse(paths[i])
    root = tree.getroot()
    for keyword in root.find(".//keywords"):
        if keyword.text is not None:
            keywords[i].append(keyword.text) # change is here
```

Comment: Now works perfectly. I was not building it correctly.  for i in range(len(paths)) and then I can access to data with the right configuration of lists. Thank you

Comment: No problem :)
It would be nice of you if you accepted my answer as the correct one, and also accepted your answer for your other question if it sovled your problem.